# VBA - Copy Function from one sheet to another creating #REF formula not sure why

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I created a Copy function to copy the row data from 1 worksheet to another worksheet. The Copy function worked fine but then when I see the cell in which data is copied I see there is formula generated on the cells as shown below . I dont know why?

"=#REF!*$P20*(1-$DX20)" This formula I can see in the cells in which data was copied into.

```
Sub Process_Calc()
    
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long: n = 20
Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsCalcAndOutput As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet 'specify each type

With Worksheets("Project_and_capex_costs")
    For i = 10 To 10
        If .Cells(i, 5) <> "" Then
            Range(.Cells(i, "BP"), Cells(i, "DC")).Copy _
                    Worksheets("DC_price_calc").Cells(n, "D") 'start at row 7?
                    
                    
            'n = n + 1 'update so that we don't overwrite next time
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I found the reason . The cells from which I am copying the data has formulas. How can I paste only values? without formulas?

Comment: Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Comment: Hi Fernando can you please help me with original code.. Its in the loop and I am very new to VBA coding. I would really appreciate your help please.

Comment: Did the `.PasteSpecial` solve your problem?  If it did, and you have another question, please ask a new question.

Comment: Hi I tried adding .I created a Copy function  in the line as Range(.Cells(i, "BP"), Cells(i, "DC")).Copy _                    Worksheets("DC_price_calc").Cells(n, "D").PasteSpecial but it gave error

Comment: Am I doing anything wrong? Please if you help me with correct code as per my requirement

Comment: `.Range(.Cells(i, "BP"), Cells(i, "DC")).Copy` on one row, `Worksheets("DC_price_calc").Cells(n, "D").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` on the next.  They have to be two separate commands.  Also note I've put `.` in front of `Range` so it works with the `With` statement - currently only the cells were looking at the correct sheet, the range was looking at whatever the active sheet is.